# Can 2 items be added/taken away from a stack in push down automata at once?

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar, computational-mathematics

Here is a language and 2 ways (I hope) of representing it with a PDA.

[image: examples]

Can I use the notation (b,a $\to$ ee) or anything of the like, to take away 2 items from the top of a list at once? Such as I have used in example A. Or do I need to work around this by using a PDA like in example B?

Generally checking my work is also appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. The shorthand $(a,b \to xyz)$ is often used, but means something else than what you're trying to do here. Recall that by $(a,b \to c)$ we mean that $a$ is the symbol that is read, $b$ is the symbol on top of the stack that is replaced with $c$. $(a,b \to xyz)$ is then usually taken to mean that $(a,b \to x) \to (\varepsilon,\varepsilon \to y) \to (\varepsilon,\varepsilon \to z)$, in which case $(a,b \to \varepsilon \varepsilon)$ would be the same as $(a,b \to \varepsilon)$.

As far as I can see, your solution B is also not correct, since you never check that there are twice as many b's as there are a's. Here is my attempt at an answer.
[image]

Notice that the start state is also an accept state since $m \geq 0$.